# Where is the attack contract used for the dao attack?

Tags: solidity, the-dao, reentrant-attacks

I studied The DAO attack.
I want to see attack contract.
but I found just child dao(0x304a554a310C7e546dfe434669C62820b7D83490)

Reentrant attack is needed fallback function.
How can I find the contract that is used for the actual attack where the code exists?
Do you have any source code?

Comment: Interesting question. If you don't find the source, you could always decompile from binary code. And the binary code is there, stored.

Comment: @Nulik hum, where is 'there'. lost link? child dao is same to The DAO code.
so i can't find fallback function.

Comment: the binary code is stored on the blockchain, and everyone can see it.

Comment: is bytecode decompile easy? I found serveral candidates. but solidity code is not in etherscan. so i tried to decompile used porosity that bytecode decompiler. but It seems that there is an error without abi. so I can't find who is call 'splitDAO'